# What is the legal status of civil unions in Poland

Tags: poland

From time to time local media in my country (Romania) argues about civil union which is not yet allowed. Doing some research, I chose Poland as a reference as I perceived relatively socially conservative (e.g. [both Poland and Romania strongly oppose same-sex marriage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognition_of_same-sex_unions_in_Europe#Opinion_polls)).

Wikipedia has an entire [article dedicated to same sex unions in Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognition_of_same-sex_unions_in_Poland):

> In 2004, under a left-wing Government, the Senate approved a bill
>   allowing gay and lesbian people to register their relationships as
>   civil unions
>
> Following the 2015 parliamentary elections, the social conservative
>   Law and Justice party (PiS) formed the new Government. PiS is opposed
>   to registered partnerships.
>
> A new registered partnership bill was proposed on 12 February 2018 by
>   the Modern party

The first paragraph suggests civil union is allowed, but the last ones talk about a new bill, but it is not clear if this is an improvement upon existing civil union legislation or this is suppose to allow civil unions.

**Question:** What is the legal status of civil unions in Poland?

Comment: This appears to be a "what is the law" question instead of a "why is this the law" question. Such questions are better asked on Law Stack Exchange than Politics Stack Exchange. I will migrate it.